# Repository pattern, EF with stored procedures

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, repository-pattern

We are pretty new to Entity Framework and the repository pattern, however trying to implement this into our system.

We have a domain model (logical model) built which our system will work with, which is fine. The issue is we are struggling to understand how we map the returned data from a stored procedure to this domain model.

The returned data from the stored procedure doesn't map to the entity model.

The only way I can think of doing this is purely by just executing the data reader, looping through the datareader, and assign each item directly, which seems dated...

From a google search "DataMapping" seems to appear,  however, cannot see any examples of how to implement this from a stored procedure to a domain model, 
only stored procedure to entity model.

Comment: Why are you using Entity Framework at all if you're simply calling stored procs?  That's a TON of overhead for very little gain.  If you're only going to call stored procs, you should switch to something like Dapper which will do the object mapping for you without the overhead.  What you're doing now is adding a lot of cruft for little to no value.

Answer (score 0):

Let me ask a question.

If you had decided to use plain ADO.NET to do the mapping, would you have been done by now? Had everyone in the team understood to 100% what the code did?

Sometimes we just seem to try to apply new technology without really understanding why and what benefit it gives us. What advantage have you seen with Entity Framework? What kind of time saving do you see in version 1 contra version 5 of your application? What happens if the ORM fails? Will everyone in your team know why it fails?

If you are just using stored procedures it might be better to keep it simple (ADO.NET) or using a more lightweight mapper like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) or [Massive](https://github.com/FransBouma/Massive).

Comment: to answer the first two questions,  yes and yes, and so initially, we would probably stick with the loop. however,  id like to gain an understanding of how to achieve this type of mapping.. Ive seen procs  working with ef, however, the returned data directly maps to entities, and then the entities map to the domain model within the business layer.